# Como corrigir o erro de codificação no sistema dotenv com postgresql? new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string')

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, postgresql, express.js

Estou tentando conectar ao banco de dados **postgresql**, utilizando **dotenv** para gerenciar as variáveis de ambiente. No código abaixo quando utilizo **process.env** ocorre o seguinte **erro, apenas para os campos password e database**:

> throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password
> must be a string')

```
 require('dotenv').config();

// //Não funciona
const uri = {
    user:process.env.db_test_user,
    password:process.env.db_test_password,
    host:process.env.db_test_host,
    port:process.env.db_test_port,
    database:process.env.db_test_database
};
```

Alterando o código para passar uma **string para o password e database**, o código funciona normalmente:

```
//funciona
const uri = {
    user:process.env.db_test_user,
    password:'password',
    host:process.env.db_test_host,
    port:process.env.db_test_port,
    database:'database'
};
```

Tentei modificar o sistema de encriptação em **postgresql.conf** e **pg_hba.conf** mas não houve diferença no resultado, a codificação do banco é utf-8.

alguém saberia uma solução para este problema?

Adicionando informações solicitadas por @Danizavtz
:

> .env

```
db_test_password='password'
db_test_host='127.0.0.1'
db_test_port=5432
db_test_database='database'
db_test_user='user'

console.log(process.env.db_test_password);
output: undefined

console.log(process.env.db_test_database);
output: undefined
```

- Todos os outros campos funcionam normalmente como demonstrado no
  exemplo da pergunta
- Somente o password e o database apresentam erro ao tentar atribui-los com process.env
- Se atribuídos diretamente como    string a conexão funciona
  normalmente!

**Estrutura do projeto:**

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin
├── cd
├── databases
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── photorec.se2
├── photorec.ses
├── public
├── routes
└── views
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar um exemplo de como está o arquivo .env? O que ocorre quando faz um console.log da variável password? Ela possui o valor esperado? O que está passando como valor é uma string ou uma chave de certificado?(.pem ou .key)

Comment: @Danizavtz editei a pergunta para incluir as informações que você solicitou!

Comment: pelo que eu vi, pode ser um erro de configuração, verifique se o arquivo `.env` está na raiz do seu projeto.

Comment: Sim .env está na raiz, e como eu disse as outras variáveis funcionam normalmente.

Comment: Vi que muitas outras pessoas tiveram problema semelhante, mais não encontrei nenhuma solução até o momento.

Comment: Caro, Estava com o mesmo problema, mas resolvi colocando o .env na raiz do projeto, mesmo que todo meu código esteja dentro de ../src

Comment: pois é, foi isso que eu falei no meu comentário mas o cara lá disse que a .env estava no local correto.

Comment: Adicionei a estrutura do projeto. O que acho estranho é somente duas das variáveis de ambiente apresentarem problema, as outras 3 funcionam como deveriam.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Isso ocorre quando o valor da variável não está definido ou não é uma string válida por questões de codificação no arquivo (ex. o arquivo pode não estar no encoding correto).

Uma maneira de depurar se o seu arquivo `.env` está carregando as variáveis de ambiente devidamente é utilizando o `console.log`.

Para fazer essa verificação e confirmar se os valores estão sendo carregados devidamente, faça o seguinte:

Logo após o comando:

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env) // remova após confirmar que está funcionando
```

Verifique se os valores estão sendo carregados do arquivo `.env` corretamente.

### Não tenho certeza qual o diretório devo colocar o meu arquivo `.env`

Neste caso a melhor abordagem é passar um caminho absoluto da localização do seu arquivo `.env`. É possível passar o caminho absoluto para o seu arquivo `.env` passando como argumento o valor `path` para a função ***config()***, da seguinte forma:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/caminho/para/seu/.env' });
```

### Meu arquivo não utiliza utf-8 como encoding no arquivo .env

Neste caso a biblioteca também trata esses arquivos, basta passar outro  argumento do parâmetro `encoding` na função ***config()*** da seguinte forma:

```
require('dotenv').config({ encoding: 'latin1' })
```

### O problema ainda persiste

Neste caso a melhor solução é ligar o modo debug da lib `'dotenv'`.

Isso é possível da seguinte forma:

```
require('dotenv').config({ debug: true });
```

Assim terá mensagens mais inteligíveis de onde procurar pelo erro e identificar qual a causa raiz do problema.

Eu simulei um problema em minha aplicação, aqui eu removi o arquivo .env do diretório correto. E esta foi a mensagem que apareceu quando eu habilitei o modo debug.

> [dotenv][DEBUG] Failed to load /home/usuario/app/.env ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/usuario/app/.env'

Todas as informações contidas aqui estão disponíveis na documentação da biblioteca [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)